# How to export the result to .csv? with ServerName as first column and online/offline as second column

Tags: powershell

I am trying to export the result of the powershell to csv with $server as the first column and online/offline as the second column. There are many column i want to define actually. I think this is a good start. Please let me know how to achieve this.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
$ServerName = "TDL498", "TDL498123", "TDL498456"
foreach ($Server in $ServerName)
{

    if (test-Connection -ComputerName $Server -Count 2 -Quiet)
    {

        write-Host "$Server Online" -ForegroundColor Green 
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$Server Offline"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by making a PSCustomObject. [*grin*] as far as i can tell, there is no need to set any special error handling with the `Test-Connection` cmdlet since it returns a `False/True` for connection tests with the `-Quiet` parameter.

```
$ComputerNameList = @(
    'LocalHost'
    '10.0.0.1'
    '127.0.0.1'
    'BetterNotBeThere'
    $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )

$Results = foreach ($CNL_Item in $ComputerNameList)
    {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $CNL_Item
        Online = Test-Connection -ComputerName $CNL_Item -Count 1 -Quiet
        }
    }

# on screen
$Results

# to csv file
$Results |
    Export-Csv -LiteralPath "$env:TEMP\MuhammadSuhailAsrulsani_ComputerStatus.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

output to screen ...

```
ComputerName     Online
------------     ------
LocalHost          True
10.0.0.1          False
127.0.0.1          True
BetterNotBeThere  False
[MySysName]        True
```

CSV file content ...

```
"ComputerName","Online"
"LocalHost","True"
"10.0.0.1","False"
"127.0.0.1","True"
"BetterNotBeThere","False"
"[MySysName]","True"
```